# How get a text at a special position

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I have a pdf and i want to do a function who can take the text in a square position.

for example i give this rec at my function (275.3404235839844, 63.08277130126953, 353.384765625, 85.0596923828125)

and it returns me the text in this rec "hello world". (if i give an other rec, it will give me the text on a pdf).

The problem is, pdftotext delete the position.

Is there a library who can helps me? i searched on tika documentation and on Fitz documentation but i found nothing.

Thanks for yours answers.